# Regex- To handle null (when no characters are present between expressions)

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex situation.

My text looks like :

```
text='abcd<a href="></a></div>abcd<i><a href=">World Bank</a>'
```

I want to capture all the hyperlinks, The regex I have written is given below-

```
re.findall("<a href=.+?>(.+?)</a>", text, re.DOTALL)
```

When I run this it given me an output:

```
['</a></div>abcd<i><a href=">World Bank']
```

The above output occurs because there is no character between

```
<a href="></a>
```

When I insert any character between the above expressions, I get Correct output.

From the above text I need an output that is

```
['World Bank']
```

How can I modify the regex to get the above output.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse what appears to be broken HTML with a regular expression?

Comment: [Why not try an XML parser instead?](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/)

Comment: @wap26 why suspicious? Any character, at least once, as few times as possible (non-greedy). Zero or more characters, as many times as possible (greedy) is very different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the other answerer, don't use regex for parsing html files.

```
>>> import re
>>> text='abcd<a href="></a></div>abcd<i><a href=">World Bank</a>'
>>> re.findall(r"(?s)<a href=.+?>([^<>]+)</a>", text)
['World Bank']
```

`[^<>]+` negated character class which matches any character but not of `<` or `>`, one or more times. So this would capture  `World Bank` only.

Let me explain why findall produces the undesired output.

```
<a href=.+?>(.+?)</a>
```

`<a href=.+?>` matches all the opening anchor tag.
`(.+?)</a>` captures **one** or more characters non-greedily until the closing `a` tag is reached. So this would match all the charcaters `</a></div>abcd<i><a href=">World Bank` until the next `</a>`. If you use `(.*?)` then you get two outputs, an empty string and `World Bank`

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sam do you know the reason for the undesired output?

Comment: Ya, I guess greedy search. Because when I tried  *? instead of +?   The outputs were ['', 'World Bank']

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use an *HTML Parser* instead?

Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: text = 'abcd<a href="></a></div>abcd<i><a href=">World Bank</a>'
In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

In [4]: [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all("a")]
Out[4]: [u'World Bank']
```

Comment: Hi alecxe, Thanks for the answer, However, I cant use the technique you suggested, I've other regexes to exclude, also there are many scenarios, which wouldn't be handled if I use beautiful soup.

Comment: @Sam sure, that's okay. Would be great if you would provide some scenarios that you think could not be handled by `BeautifulSoup`. Is it always HTML you have your input data as?

Comment: It can handle, what I meant was, Some scenarios I don't want it to handle.  For example in wikki pages we have references like [1], [2] , [3] etc that are hyperlinked.  If I use Beautiful soup even there turn up..